# In sap hybris, is there any build-in way through which i can display label on product images?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to SAP Hybris. My requirement is to display best seller or some other label on particular products Images. I just want to know, should Hybris provide any of the properties or anything through which I can achieve this? Or do I have to add my own field in Product Model?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot / drawing of what you are expecting?

Comment: hello geffchang,on this link u can see https://grandwesternsteaks.com/beef.html?p=2      they are displaying new,out of stock,Sale ,Hot Price on product images. i want to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no approach for it generally. Actually, such "tags" are also derived from other derived values. Stock, Total quantity in OrderEntries, ....

However, if you want to "boost" a product you can make it a "TOP" product which put its automatically in front of a search result. Depending on this, you could implement a tag on the image.

Of course, you would be a able to add a "String imageTag" field to the ProductModul and if set, put on the first image on the category page and/or PDP. But that is not a default feature.

Comment: thanks @Michael for informing that there is not build-in bybris approach for tags.

Comment: If it was helpful, you might set this question to answered.